# How to isolate multi module project's tests on different JVM?

Tags: scala, sbt

i am trying to configure **sbt(scala)** in multi module project, to 
run isolated tests for each module(in a different JVM).

does someone knows how can i do it ?

Comment: does setting `fork in Test := true` achieves what you want? It will pretty much fork a new JVM when you execute Unit tests. Are you running tests in parallel?

Comment: no. According to the docs, it is just start different jvm for sbt and the run tasks. see http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Running-Project-Code.html